# Angular JS unit testing

Tags: angularjs

Angular noob - stuck on a unit testing scenario. In brief:

```
var app = angular.module("app");

    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$parse', '$http', '$window', '$location', Ctrl]);
    function Ctrl($scope, $filter, $parse, $http, $window, $location)
    {
       $scope.change = function(data)
       {
          $http.post('url', p).then(function(response)
          {
              //code to process 'change'
          } 
       }
    }

//unit test
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) 
{
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('Ctrl', { $scope: scope });

    httpBackendHandler =
        httpBackend.when("POST","/url").respond(createServerResponse());

}));
```

In a test that I'm writing, I need to test the code that runs after the http.post().then(). Currently, I call $scope.change() followed by $scope.apply().
The code "inside" the .then is called, but AFTER the test's resulting "expect"s get executed, thereby returning incorrect results. How do I "timeout" until the .then() code has executed so that test can get accurate results?

Comment: Please disregard - the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong without seeing actual tests. But your tests might be failing because `$httpBackend` doesn't return result until `$httpBackend.flush()` method is called. You should call `httpBackend.flush()` somewhere between controller method call and `$scope.apply()`.